# Why is my Rest API not working with my ip?

Tags: api, get, postman

There is json i need to access with a GET request, it has no restrictions, my friends can access it from their location.

However, from my device (tried on Chrome, Firefox, VS Code, Edge), and even from my phone, both have a different IP, I cannot access it.

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Xss-Protection: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 08:46:09 GMT
```

This is the output from an online request testing app, and it works.
Is there anything in this output that can give me a hint on what to change to make it accessible from any device?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the JSON located? If it is at your friends, try port forwarding at his place. If it isn't, we will need to see your code and we will need more context. Internet access can get complicated.